# Why when using redux-thunk, the inner function returns something?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I often see code when using redux-thunk, the inner function returning something, such as in [the official Redux async example](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/):

[The code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js):

```
const fetchPosts = subreddit => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
  return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
}

const shouldFetchPosts = (state, subreddit) => {
  // return true or false
}

export const fetchPostsIfNeeded = subreddit => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
    return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
  }
}
```

so `fetchPostsIfNeeded()` is a thunk, and so is `fetchPosts()`. They both return a function, and the function returns something too.  Now this function is actually called by the middleware, and I don't think the returned value is ever used. So why does the inner function inside the thunk keep on returning something instead of just invoking it?  The code could have been:

```
const fetchPosts = subreddit => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
  fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
}

const shouldFetchPosts = (state, subreddit) => {
  // return true or false
}

export const fetchPostsIfNeeded = subreddit => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
    dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns a promise that allows you to add a callback in `then` chain and do something when, as in the exaple, a subredit post is fetched.

```
export const fetchPostsIfNeeded = subreddit => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
    dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit)).then(() => doSomething());
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean, the `dispatch()` will return whatever that inner function returns? If so, then it can be a feature that is sometimes useful... but not in that current example

Comment: I tried returning `123` in the inner function of `fetchPosts()` and that `dispatch()` in `fetchPostsIfNeeded()` is returning `123` as well... so it just seem "whatever the inner function wants to return"? So the rule is, the `dispatch(fn)` will return whatever `fn()` returns

Comment: Yes, you are right. See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition